# set new views in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection

after searching on google and stack overflow don't succeed to figure out my problem…

from first view (login view) accessing data from sqlite3 . for valid users app has a new view to download data and
i am sending a Request by NSURLConnection, i don't know where is the problem just getting

```
lldv error ,, thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1, address = 0.------ (different every time)
```

this is my code so far..
in my .h file

```
@property(nonatomic ,retain) NSURLConnection *URLConnection;
```

im .m i synthesize properly and using it as

```
message = @""; // SQL query in XML formate
URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/xmlserver/xxxxx.php"];
Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[Request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[Request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError *Error = nil;
//NSLog(@"%@",message);
                                                  //here i am getting the error…. 
URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:Request delegate:self];

if (URLConnection)              
{
    {
        NSData *XmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
        ErrorParsing=NO;
        NSLog(@"Get data of XML...%ld",(long)QueryNumber);
        XmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: XmlFile];
        [XmlParser setDelegate:self];
        [XmlParser parse];
    }
}
```

One more thing wondering me that when i am calling this on the same view it was just perfect , but now giving me the above error… 
need your help on this issue… :(

sorry but i am editing my question 
actually this is not the NSURLConnection error at all, because i have set a new button on this view and on button pressed i am calling a new view … and here is the same issue i am facing ….
this is my new view calling code

```
MainView *Main = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:Main.view];
```

and already include Mainview.h file in this view's .h file
now please lead me to figure out the issue…

Comment: Where are you setting its delegate?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi didn't get your point what u are asking… actually i am new in iOS

Comment: Did you set `NSURLConnectionDelegate` in the target class?

**YourClass<NSURLConnectionDelegate>**

Comment: You are simply opening the new viewController?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the ViewController as a subView, which is wrong.. instead you have to open the new ViewController.

```
MainView *main = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:main animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: move on next view … NSLog of new view is showed in console but again crash with lldv error … :(

Comment: yes it worked … actually i am using one another part of my code this subview code … changed it as well and now its working perfectly… thanks a lot & love you

Comment: Love u too... n Happy Coding

Comment: how i can set a bool type global variable that can be accessed in all views or in all classes...

Comment: make it a public property. In Interface(.h) file **@property(assign) BOOL myBool;** and in implementation(.m) file synthesize it **@synthesize myBool**. You can use it in any class using the class instance in which it is declared.

Comment: yes it is accessible but not responding as true or false…what should i do now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48951/discussion-between-himanshu-joshi-and-zaibi)